# How to interpret complex probability of superposition state?

Tags: quantum-state, probability

I have one qubit and I apply two gates to it: H and T, which yields the following superposition:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |0\rangle + \frac{1+i}{2}|1\rangle
$$

Now I want to calculate probability of 0 and 1 state:

$$
\left(A_1\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
\left(A_2\right)^2 = \left(\frac{i+1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{i}{2}
$$
$$
S = \left(A_1\right)^2 + \left(A_2\right)^2 = \frac{1+i}{2}
$$
$$
P(A_i) = \frac{A_i^2}{S}
$$
according to prior equations i receive following values
$$
P(0) = \frac{1}{1+i}  \land  P(1) = \frac{i}{i+1}
$$

I was expecting to get $A_i=0.5$ however $P(0) + P(1) = 1$

How do I interpret this results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to take the absolute value.

The [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) for computing measurement outcome probability from the state vector amplitudes says that the probability is the square of the *[magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers)* of the amplitude.

In your case, we get

$$
\left(A_1\right)^2 = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right|^2 = \frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
\left(A_2\right)^2 = \left|\frac{i+1}{2}\right|^2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 =\frac{1}{2}
$$

as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Just to note that the complex number also specify a quantum phase of a qubit. In this particular case
$$
\frac{1+i}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{4}},
$$
so the relative phase is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

You can rewrite your qubit state as
$$
|q\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} |1\rangle).
$$

Now, you easily see that probability of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ is $\frac{1}{2} = \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)^2$ in both cases and the phase is $\pi/4$.